# 1980s book about the Devil being on trial in the Pacific Northwest

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book in the 1980s.

I seem to remember it taking place in the Pacific Northwest, maybe the Seattle area.

In it, the Devil was on trial. He picked his lawyer to represent him and prove that he existed. All the drama seemed to play out in the courthouse while he locked the jury and attendants in the courthouse until the end.

I can't really remember how it ended but I believe everything went back to normal and everyone forgot what just happened or something to that effect.

Comment: I don't think this fits, but just in case, Irving Washington's short-story 'The Devil and Tom Walker'..?